# How do I make a nested for loop in R that multiples X & X?

Tags: r, loops, nested, rstudio

So I'm trying to do a nested for loop that will multiple 1:100 with 1:100 (10,000 possible combinations). So 1*1, 1*2 ... 1* 100. Once it reaches 100, I want it to repeat, so 2*1, 2*2, 2*100.

Of note: I need to be doing this using for loops

```
table<-matrix(ncol=3, nrow=100*100)
for (i in 1:100) {
  for (z in 1:100){
    answer<-i*z
    table[i,] <- c(i,z,answer)
  }
}
```

Here's my code above. It seems like an easy fix, but I'm missing something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
out <- outer(1:100, 1:100)
```

It can be converted to a 3-column data.frame with `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
out2 <- melt(out)
```

---

In the `for` loop, we need

```
for (i in 1:100) {
   for (z in 1:100){
       answer<-i*z
       table[i, z] <- answer
   }
  }
  table[i, z] <- answer
```

where

```
table <- matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
```

---

Checking the output

```
all.equal(out, table)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

If we need the 'i', 'z'

```
out2 <- transform(expand.grid(i = 1:100, z = 1:100), answer = i * z)
```

---

Or with `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
crossing(i = 1:100, z = 1:100) %>%
   mutate(answer = i * z)
# A tibble: 10,000 x 3
#       i     z answer
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     1     2     2
# 3     1     3     3
# 4     1     4     4
# 5     1     5     5
# 6     1     6     6
# 7     1     7     7
# 8     1     8     8
# 9     1     9     9
#10     1    10    10
# … with 9,990 more rows
```

---

Or in a `for`loop

```
table1 <- c()
for(i in 1:100) {
   for(z in 1:100){
      table1 <- rbind(table1, c(i, z, i * z))
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, however, that's not really what I'm trying to do. I'm hoping the table will have

i, z, answer
1 1  1
2 1  2
...
etc

Comment: @Bailey In your descriptioni, it says `1*1, 1*2 ... 1* 100. Once it reaches 100, I want it to repeat, so 2*1, 2*2, 2*100`.

Comment: Thanks Akrun for answering, but I am hoping it would have 3 columns, with i,z,answer as the column titles

Comment: @Bailey updatd the post

Comment: Thanks again, is that possible to do using a for loop?
I'm trying to do something more complicated, but it'll require the use of loops

Comment: thanks @akrun, you are amazing. are you able to explain why the first code didn't work?

Comment: @Bailey Did you meant the code in your question or from my post

Comment: the code from my question, so im guessing it has something to do with setting it as a matrix rather than an array?

Comment: @Bailey The issue is wiith `table[i,]` where `i` is only from 1 to 100 whereas you have rows from 1:10000